# I have no option to create new sql server database in vs2013

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I installed SQL server 2012 and I have been using it with vs2012. For some reason, now that I have installed vs2013, if I go to "Create New SQL server database...", the option is grayed out.

Just to clarify:

I go to the server explorer tag -> right click data connections. In that list of options the "Create New SQL Server Database..." option is on the list but it is grayed out. Is it necessary for me to link vs2013 to it in some way? I may have done this as part of the original SQL server 2012 installation but I do not want to mess up that setup inadvertently.

Edit: It may (or may not) be worth mentioning that I can actually create Databases for vs2013 projects with vs2012. It is mainly a matter of it being awkward and just incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

An out-of-date of VS2012 SQL Server Data Tools can cause conflict with built in tools for VS2013.  Download the latest version of [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027).

Comment: I have just checked the date on my installation and it was installed October. The link you provided seems to point to the same install file that I used unless there is something I have missed. I have "SSDTSetup.exe" downloaded 15 Oct.

Comment: Actually... thinking about it, those are the tools for VS2012. This blog post also seems to highlight a few issues. Not sure if they are related to my problem or not though. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/10/10/updated-sql-server-data-tools-october-2013.aspx I may have to just continue creating them in vs2012. :(